# Make text appear on website as you type in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, input, event-listener

Basically, I would like whatever I am typing be printed out in another area of my website. I am assuming I would need an eventListener but not sure how to do the display text as I type part.

```
<tr id="row">
   <td>
      <input class="item-container" type="text" id="item-input5" maxlength="128">
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the input I  want the eventListener to call: input class="item-container".

Comment: I got rid of the other td tag as that was just there for reference. I do not want that tag to be a part of the eventListener. Only the item container input tag is what I'm concerned with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `input` event and read the value property of the input element. You can then use this value as textContent in another element or use the value in any other way you'd like.

```js
document.querySelector('#item-input5').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  document.querySelector('#result_text').textContent = event.currentTarget.value
});
```

```html
<tr id="row">
  <td>
    <input class="item-container" type="text" id="item-input5" maxlength="128">
  </td>
  <div id="result_text"></div>
</tr>
```